# passing value from data table to dialog

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a problem with passing data from dataTable witch is populated from database to dialog for editing values.

izmenaPredmeta.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Obrada predmeta</title>
    </h:head>
<h:body>
    <center>
        <h:form>
            <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
            <h:dataTable var="list" value="#{pred.getPredmets()}" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="lightgray">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Naziv</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{list.naziv}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Akronim</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{list.akronim}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Semestar</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{list.semestar}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Godina</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{list.god}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Odsek</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{list.odsek}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Aktivan</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{list.drzise}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Edit</f:facet>
                    <h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{pred.edit()}" onclick="PF('dlg3').show();"> 
                        <f:param name="idp" value="#{list.idpred}"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                    <p:dialog header="Edit" widgetVar="dlg3" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="bounce" height="350">
                        <h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2" cellpadding="5" border="1" bgcolor="gray">
                            <h:outputText value="Naziv"/>
                            <p:inputText style="width: 97%"  value="#{pred.naziv}" required="true" requiredMessage="Naziv je obavezan"/>
                            <h:outputText value="Akronim"/>
                            <p:inputText style="width: 97%" value="#{pred.akronim}" required="true" requiredMessage="Akronim je obavezan"/>
                            <h:outputText value="Semestar"/>
                            <p:inputText style="width: 97%" value="#{pred.semestar}" required="true" requiredMessage="Semestar je obavezan"/>
                            <h:outputText value="Godina"/>
                            <p:inputText style="width: 97%" value="#{pred.god}" required="true" requiredMessage="Godina je obavezna"/>
                            <h:outputText value="Odsek"/>
                            <p:inputText style="width: 97%" value="#{pred.odsek}" required="true" requiredMessage="Odsek je obavezan"/>
                            <h:outputText value="Drzi se"/>
                            <p:inputText style="width: 97%" value="#{pred.drzise}" required="true" requiredMessage="Drzi se je obavezno"/>
                            <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{pred.upPredmet()}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:dialog>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
                    <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{pred.delPredmet()}">
                        <f:param rendered="msgs" name="id" value="#{list.idpred}"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </center>
</h:body>
```

and function from PredmetBean.java @ViewScoped implements Serializable

```
// getter's, setter's and other functions  
public void edit(){
    ArrayList<Predmet> PrList = Predmet.getPredmets();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idp"));
    for(Predmet pr : PrList){
        if( pr.getIdpred() == id ){
            this.setIdPred(pr.getIdpred());
            this.setNaziv(pr.getNaziv());
            this.setAkronim(pr.getAkronim());
            this.setSemestar(pr.getSemestar());
            this.setGod(pr.getGod());
            this.setOdsek(pr.getOdsek());
            this.setDrzise(pr.getDrzise());
        }
    }
}
```

when clicked on edit button dialog should open with values from row in witch the button is click. But only thing i get is dialog try to open and break and then requiredMessages pops up all over. 
When in dialog for value is list.somename dialog shows and populate the fileds with the last object value in list. 
If someone have idea how to solve this or some other method for editing user values without going to other page it would be great.

Comment: Take a good look at the PrimeFaces showcase

Comment: try removing the <p:dialog> tag outside your h:dataTable.

Comment: @Fritz thx i have half less requiredMessages  popups now... but still getting them.

Comment: could you edit your post and add more details on what you did to cut the number of messages to half? so that from there we'll continue checking what's wrong. thanks

Comment: @Fritz sorry for latte replay but i manage to solve it at the end. Thx for your interest and help, that put me in the right track.

Comment: that's great. go SO community! :D

Answer (score -1):

Keep the p:dialog outside the form and use binding attribute in your dataTable show in below Example.

Declare the below line your managed bean

```
private HtmlDataTable dataTable;
```

Add the below line in your dataTable

```
binding="#{managedBean.htmlDataTable}"
```

Then your edit method would be like this

```
public void edit(){

    Predmet selectedObject = (Predmet) getDataTable().getRowData(); 
}
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: Why do you need binding for this? PrimeFaces showcase has several examples that fully function without binding...

Comment: if we are going completly with prime face component thats fine, I given a refrence for how to use it in h:dataTable component

Comment: You do most of the transferring with an h:datatable without binding to.. Just not sure about the ajax part